# Speed difference: separate functor VS operator() inside a big class with *this

Tags: c++, performance, operators, this, operator-keyword

I'm using the c++ STL heap algorithms, and I wrote a wrapper class around it so I could do some other stuff.  When I tried to use the code below, for example:

```
//! Min-heap wrapper class.
class FMMHeap{
public:
    FMMHeap(Vector &phi) : _phi(phi) {}
    bool operator()(unsigned p1, unsigned p2) {return fabs(_phi(p1)) > fabs(_phi(p2)); }
    inline void pop(){ pop_heap(_heap.begin(),_heap.end(),*this); _heap.pop_back(); }
    [...lots of other stuff...]
    vectorU32 _heap;
    Vector &_phi;
}
```

It was wayyyyy slower than when I had a separate function object like this:

```
struct HeapSort{
public:
    HeapSort(Vector &phi) : _phi(phi) {}
    bool operator()(unsigned p1, unsigned p2) {return fabs(_phi(p1)) > fabs(_phi(p2)); }
private:
    Vector &_phi;
};

class FMMHeap{
public:
    FMMHeap(Vector &phi) : cmp(phi) {}
    inline void pop(){ pop_heap(_heap.begin(),_heap.end(),cmp); _heap.pop_back(); }
    [...lots of other stuff...]
    vectorU32 _heap;
    HeapSort cmp;
}
```

I'm not sure why this is.  Is the slowdown coming from *this because the class has a lot of data?  That seems odd.  Or is it something to do with how the function object is used?

Comment: You should make your operator() const. Predicates are not expected to have any side effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not certain: but maybe `pop_heap` ends up copying the functor object you pass in.
The copy for your `FMMHeap` would be more expensive than the simple `HeapSort`

Comment: Yes, its passing the comparison function object by value.

Comment: More generally, most STL algorithms pass the predicate object by value, so it's better to use separate objects there.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest speedup of the STL containers is the inlining of them, such that the compiler can work out how to remove and reorder things.

Its a good guess that the compiler manages to inline the external functor in a way that const propogation is stopping it from doing so in the slow version.

What happens to the slow version if the bool operator is const?